Electron won't open window after calling `electron .`
This is using Electron with Angular 18.
All the setup seems fine, as per creating a JS file to host electron, include it in package.json. What is one of the reason it don't open upon calling electron .? And worse, it crash without telling you a reason.

Please have a read of [ask]. In such cases, it is important to include relevant pieces of your package.json file as well as any console output you might be getting, even if it doesn't seem relevant.

In the end, one found out because one don't use main.js, rather, one uses electron.js. It might have some clash inside, one don't know, but changing the name of the electron hosting file to other than electron.js (one hadn't tried other names other than main.js) and the window pop up miraculously.
